# Disabling specific button in ToolBar while cursor is in the editable portion of a widget? (CKEditor version 4.5.11)

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am wondering if it is possible to disable a specific widget in the ToolBar in the 'editables' portion of the widget code? I currently have the below code set up for a widget. Within these selectors, I do not want the user adding in a specific widget in the ToolBar.

```
this.editables = {
  content1: {
      selector: '.content1',
      allowedContent: this.allowedContent

    },
    content2: {
      selector: '.content2',
      allowedContent: this.allowedContent
    },
    content3: {
      selector: '.content3',
      allowedContent: this.allowedContent
    }
  };
```

I have tried adding in the below logic but it breaks my code.

```
var oWidget= editor.getCommand('customWidget')
oWidget.setState(CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_DISABLED);
```

Any advise would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to check for user selection event, and if selection in `editable portion` enable command.

Something like this -

```
CKEDITOR.instances["textarea"].on( 'selectionChange', function( evt ) {
    // get desired command from ckeditor 
    var myCommand = this.getCommand( 'CKEDITOR_COMMAND_NAME' );
    var mySelection = null;
    // check if something is selected
    var mySelection = this.getSelection().getNative() || this.window.$.getSelection() || this.document.$.selection;
    if (!mySelection) {
    // if not stay disable
        myCommand.disable();
    } else {
   //if yes enable command
    myCommand.enable();
    }

});
```